# Как подключить QScrollArea к QLabel из PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qscrollarea

Как подключить `QScrollArea` к `QLabel` из *PyQt5* так, чтобы я двигал скролл, а лабел с большим текстом двигался в направлении скролл бара?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff;")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 441, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(" ")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 10, 111, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 51))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 761, 501))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.label_2.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.label_2.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_2.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 90, 21, 481))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Искать!"))
```

[image: Как должно выглядить]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Класс `QScrollArea` обеспечивает просмотр с прокруткой на другой виджет.
>
> Область прокрутки используется для отображения содержимого дочернего виджета во фрейме.
> Если виджет превышает размер фрейма, в представлении могут быть полосы прокрутки,
> чтобы можно было просматривать всю область дочернего виджета.
> Дочерний виджет должен быть указан с помощью `setWidget()`.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#details

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(784, 543)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("/* VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */\n"
" QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: rgb(45, 45, 68);\n"
"    width: 14px;\n"
"    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"/*  HANDLE BAR VERTICAL */\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 122);\n"
"    min-height: 30px;\n"
"    border-radius: 7px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover{    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"/* BTN TOP - SCROLLBAR */\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);\n"
"    height: 15px;\n"
"    border-top-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"    border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"    subcontrol-position: top;\n"
"    subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"/* BTN BOTTOM - SCROLLBAR */\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);\n"
"    height: 15px;\n"
"    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"    subcontrol-position: bottom;\n"
"    subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"/* RESET ARROW */\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"/* HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR - HOMEWORK */\n"
"QScrollBar:horizontal {\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal\n"
"{\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal\n"
"{\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 68);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('QLineEdit', self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 441, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(" ")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 10, 111, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 51))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("boy.jpg").scaled(211, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        
        
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet(" QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: rgb(56, 56, 85);\n"
" }")
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-319, 0, 1218, 1218))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 761, 501))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.label_2.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.label_2.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label_2.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_2.setText("label_2")
# ?        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 784, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Искать!"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.label_2.setText(
            '<h1 style="color:white; font-size: 33px;">Welcome to PyQt5~</h1><br>'+
            '<b style="color:white; font-size: 15px;">Как подключить ScrollBar '
            'к Label из PyQt5 так чтобы я двигал скролл а лабел с большим '
            'текстом двигался в направлении скролл бара?</b><br>' * 20
        )
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!